# Xamarin Android, java class ListenableFuture is defined multiple times, with new Andriod App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I created a brand spanking new **Xamarin Android App** in **Visual Studio 2022**.

I then referenced the *v1.0.17.2* of the **Xamarin.Stripe.Terminal.Android** library as I need to perform some transactions on a card reader.

I compiled the solution without touching a line of code and I got the following issue

> **Type com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture is defined multiple times**: C:\Users\XYZ.nuget\packages\xamarin.google.guava.listenablefuture\1.0.0.2\buildTransitive\monoandroid50\guava-listenablefuture.jar:com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.class, obj\Debug\120\lp\54\jl\guava-28.1-android.jar:com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.class

You can see two jar references in the error message

> **1.0.0.2\buildTransitive\monoandroid50\guava-listenablefuture.jar**

> **obj\Debug\120\lp\54\jl\guava-28.1-android.jar**

If I take the full java command line built by Visual Studio, and I then remove the reference the jar

> **1.0.0.2\buildTransitive\monoandroid50\guava-listenablefuture.jar**

then java compiles correctly from the command line, with a slew of warnings.

---

I'm just wondering if there is some way to exclude this JAR from the compile process in Visual Studio, so that the build can continue on correctly.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70907093/guava-in-android-dynamic-feature-module

Comment: @Bigtoe did you find an answer for this?

Comment: @fandro I need to revist this, I got a notification recently that the git repo has been updated and there may be a later nuget version there.

Comment: Thanks, if it's a public repo I can you share it? otherwise I m waiting for your feedback :)

Comment: Hi @fandro, the 2.5.2 branch has been merged into master, but they have not released a new version of the nuget packages after the build.

https://github.com/Square-Six/Xamarin.Stripe.Terminal.Android